# Kotlin: Incremental compilation with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

In the [M9](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2014/10/m9-is-here/) announcement it was said that incremental compilation is now supported. Does this also work with Gradle, especially Android? If yes, how to enable it?

Comment: In Beta 4 announcement it says "Soon: same incremental compilation support is coming to Gradle! Stay tuned." so it is on the near horizon.  That announcement: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/12/kotlin-1-0-beta-4-is-out/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: as of Kotlin 1.1.1, [Gradle incremental compilation is now enabled by default](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/03/kotlin-1-1-1-is-out/).

--- Old answer:

For now incremental compilation only works in the IDE when you use the Make algorithm supported by IntelliJ IDEA. We are looking into extending this to other build systems, but we are not there yet.

Answer (score 7):

Incremental compilation in Gradle and IDE was added in [Kotlin 1.0.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/05/kotlin-1-0-2-is-here/). It is enabled in IDE is enabled by default. To enable it for Gradle you will need to add `kotlin.incremental=true` to your `gradle.properties` file.